# Latex - Several lines of points in the table of contents in pdf

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tableofcontents

In my table of contents, between 2 sections there are several points. Look this screenshot [Bug section of table of contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyfyn.png)

There is my code

```
\section[Lecture du fichier excel avec la librairie pandas]{Lecture du fichier excel avec la librairie pandas}

La librairie pandas me permet
de lire des csv et \ des fichiers excel . Gr\^ace \`a cette librairie,
je peux transformer les donn\'ees d{\textquoteright}un format excel ou
csv , en dataframe. Un dataframe est simple \`a utiliser et tr\`es
rapide \`a lire car il est stock\'e dans la m\'emoire RAM . \ Voici un
sch\'ema repr\'esentatif :



\begin{center} \includegraphics[width=16.002cm,height=8.091cm]{MmoiredestageV10libreoffice-img5.png} \end{center}
```

My question : why there are several lines ? and how to remove it .
I am using kile
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid I found the problem.

I used the writer2latex, which convert odt to latex. And he adds lots of empty subsection. I removed it . 
Like that

```
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
```